# Database component of a simple website

Tags: database, web

I am a second year Comp Sci student applying for a job at a tech company. For this application we are put through a series of coding challenges to see if we make it through to the next round of the application. For the second round my challenge goes as follows:

● We require you to build a small website using Django and to host it locally.

● You need to be able to leverage the quick turn around time that Django allows but
also put extra effort into it so that you have a working website.

● Ensure your site has at least 3 pages and at least 1 database-driven component.

● Past examples of sites from candidates are simple sites for fictional bands, or
political candidates.

Now I have never coded a website before but have done the codecademy tutorials so I managed to put together a basic layout of a website for a musician that happens to be me since I am an amateur musician with 2 "albums".

What I don't really understand is the database component of the website. I don't really understand why I would need one.

I thought I could have my mp3's as BLOB's on the database, but I don't see how that is more advantageous than simply having the mp3's in a folder in the website.

I also thought to maybe put the mp3 metadata on the database i.e. Title, Album, Artist, Year etc. but I don't really see the point since there are too few songs to have to implement a search function on the mp3's.

Is there something I am missing here? What would your database component be if you were coding a site for a 'fictional band'?

Answer (score 0):

I would agree that it is probably overkill to use a database for building a site for some *specific* fictional band.

What they might have meant is to build a sort of CMS (content management system) style website that would let *any* band manage their *own* web site once they installed it. For example, there could be web forms that let the band add/edit new releases (without doing any programming). That would make use of a database.

Of course, a band could also just use Squarespace or something but this is meant to be an exercise.